# MsSQL Select Expression Sometimes work wrong

Tags: sql-server

I write a select expression. This show list of records according to plants. 
Sql expression is below:

```
select w.RN, w.x,  w.y, w.T, ws.z, ws1.k  
FROM Table1 w 
 FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ws ON w.a = ws.ID
 FULL OUTER JOIN  Table2 AS ws1 ON w.b = ws1.ID  
WHERE (w.CONFIRMED = 0)  
GROUP BY w.FIRMRN, w.RN, w.x,  w.y, w.T, ws.z, ws1.k  
HAVING (w.FIRMRN = {0})  
order by w.x asc, w.T desc
```

On Having Clause, w.FIRMRN catch on Session on the server. Rarely, records of One more plants is shown on the list. Why?

Comment: Did you try to break your sql and see what it individually returns? Maybe that can help

Comment: It work wrong on the server. So I don't break.

Comment: What is the result you are looking for?  Why are you grouping if you are not aggregating?

Comment: I want to show records list according to plants. Grouping for repetation rows.

Comment: Did you try `select distinct`?  May get what you are looking for more precisely.

Comment: In fact, sql work when I try to work on the sql server. but rarely on the website I click the list, there is two plants records. There is total ten plants. Why just two plants records?

Comment: might b a newbee question but what  '{'  this will do n query....as it is used "w.FIRMRN = {0}"